# Graph representation in Dr Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to represent a graph in Dr. Scheme in the following manner:

For each node I want to store it's value and a list of adjacent nodes,the problem which i'm having difficulties with is that I want the adjacent nodes to be stored as references to other nodes.

For example: I want node ny to be stored as („NY“ (l p)) where l and p are adjacent nodes,and
not as („NY“ („London“ „Paris“)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want cycles or not -- dealing with them can complicate things.
But if you want to do the representation with only lists, then [`shared`](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/shared.html#%28form._%28%28lib._scheme/shared..ss%29._shared%29%29) is your friend.  For example:

```
(shared ([NY     (list "NY"     (list London Paris))]
         [Paris  (list "Paris"  (list NY))]
         [London (list "London" (list NY))])
  (list NY Paris London))
```

If your goal is to actually write "real" code, then using your own structs would be much better than lists (but then `shared` would not work).

For the case of using promises, cycles become easy to do with just `letrec`.  Here's how the above will look in this case:

```
(letrec ([NY     (list "NY"     (delay (list London Paris)))]
         [Paris  (list "Paris"  (delay (list NY)))]
         [London (list "London" (delay (list NY)))])
  (list NY Paris London))
```

Alternatively, you can wrap a `delay` around each occurrence of a city inside the lists.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.I think I'm not supposed to use share,trying to use only basic list functions and define

Comment: John: in this case, you need to be more specific.  If this is homework, and if you're really supposed to have cycles and lists, then this will be hard.

Comment: I'm supposed to do a depth-search on a graph represented in the way I stated above.And yes it may have cycles,I'm supposed to use force and delay

Comment: John: Ah -- that makes sense.  The answer in this case is very similar to the one I gave, except using `letrec` with promises.  (I added an example above.)